# What does "DO" in "DO-160" stand for?

Tags: avionics

What does "DO" in "DO-160" stand for? Is it short for document? I have searched in internet but it only mentions the document details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it short for document?

Yes. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Category:RTCA_standards&oldid=949296669):

> The designation DO stands for "DOcument".

Comment: And the EUROCAE (European Organization for Civil Aviation Electronics) equivalent of RTCA DO-160 is ED-14.  ED stands for EUROCAE Document.  Sometimes engineers actually do things that make sense.